# How to get the GOP size of a video with ffmpeg (C)?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decoding

Is there any way to get the gop size of a video I'm decoding using the ffmpeg C API, that isn't demuxing until I find an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

AVCodecContext has an element for this but I'm not sure if it always work: `int AVCodecContext::gop_size`

Here is the link: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html

Comment: Nope, not valid for **decoding**.

Comment: I looked at that variable and it claimed my 15 gop size vid was 12.

Comment: For me too always 12 while decoding